# video chatting on Android without Internet access

Tags: android

I want to test video chatting on android phone through wireless LAN in our lab. However, most of the video chatting apps like Tango or Fringe require access to their server on the Internet. Is there a way for me to test video chatting without access to Internet server? Is setting up a SIP server a good alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you need to use SIP/VOIP.